# Swagger openapi-typescript-codegen change casing for one model

Tags: typescript, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I know you can change the casing for your project
According to the `swagger-codegen` [FAQ you are able to change the casing as such](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/FAQ#typescript:%7E:text=4098%23issuecomment%2D328142793-,TypeScript,-The%20JSON%20response):

> modelPropertyNaming
> Naming convention for the property: 'camelCase', 'PascalCase', 'snake_case' and 'original', which keeps the original name (Default: camelCase)

by using it in your query:

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-4.1.3.jar generate -i C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\OpenAPICodegen\swagger.json -g typescript-angular -o C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\OpenAPICodegen\dist --additional-properties modelPropertyNaming=origional
```

or

```
dotnet swagger tofile --output ./wwwroot/swagger/v1/swagger.yaml --yaml $(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll v1 --additional-properties modelPropertyNaming=origional
```

---

#### **Q:** How can I do it for 1 specific model?

In my project all my models in .NET go from `PascalCase` to `camelCase` which is all good. But one of my models represents a model that is being fetched from a JSON file. hence I need only **one (1)** model to have `PascalCase` while keeping the others in `camelCase`. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since there hasn't been much activity i'll post my own answer:*

---

## #1 You have to make your own SchemaFilter

```cs
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

namespace FAKD.Server.Services
{
    public class PascalCaseSchemaFilter<T> : ISchemaFilter
        where T : class
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            var properties = context.Type.GetProperties();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (context.Type == typeof(T))
                {
                    var propertyName = property.Name;
                    schema.Properties = schema.Properties.ToDictionary(
                        d => d.Key.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + d.Key.Substring(1),
                        d => d.Value
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## #2 Add filter to AddSwaggerGen Options

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(spec =>
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "backend.xml");
    spec.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
    spec.DescribeAllParametersInCamelCase();
    spec.SupportNonNullableReferenceTypes();
    var url = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("OpenApi:BaseUrl");
    spec.AddServer(new OpenApiServer { Url = url, Description = "default" });


    spec.SchemaFilter<PascalCaseSchemaFilter<MYMODELHERE>>();

});
```

## #3 Profit

```json
      "ModelA": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uuid"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "identificator": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "approvedBy": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "reviewed": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "start": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
          },
          "end": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
          },
          "aCount": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      "MYMODELHERE": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Id": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uuid"
          },
          "Type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Identificator": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "ApprovedBy": {
            "type": "string"
          },
```